# wpdb discards duplicate column names?

Tags: wpdb

using `$wpdb->get_results` I am joining two tables that have some columns in common, now normally I would expect to get
`table_a.one` and `table_b.one` both returned, but instead
I get only one returned which is the value for `table_b.one` in the position of `table_a.one`

Is there a way around this or am I forced to avoid using $wpdb?

Edit:
I need the column names.

Comment: Please show your code example.

Comment: You must refine your query defining 2 aliases for the common columns I.E. : `SELECT A.col1 as a_col, B.col1 as b_col ...`so in your response you will have *a_col* and *b_col* values

Comment: Thanks Andrea, that seems like a good solution.